# Spring MVC form valiadtion with @NotEmpty annotation, one POJO with Multiple forms

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on spring mvc with annotations.

I have a POJO with three fields **userName, password and mailId** which are annotated as **@NotEmpty**. 
I have two forms :

1. `Loginform.jsp` : contains two input fields userName and password.
2. `Forgotpassword.jsp`: contains only one input field mailId.

The problem is if I use the same pojo for both jsp forms it's giving me binding result errors, as for login.jsp I don't need mailId, and for forgotpassword.jsp I don't need userName and password, but all these fields are annotated as `@NotEmpty` in my POJO,so gives validation error.

**Q: How to deal with the situation? Do I need to create separate POJO for each Form?**

Comment: 2 different use cases and as such use 2 different objects. Don't try to reuse as that will somewhere in the future bite you.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, login and forgot-password are two very different business usecases, and as such deserve separate POJOs. Doing so would also, in future, guard you against accidently exposing the password in forgot-password page.